# Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-community-dialects for sqlite

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, sqlite

i'am trying to make a poc with springboot and hibernate :

Here is my build.gradle :

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.server'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.11.2'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.2.0.Final'
    // https://mavenlibs.com/maven/dependency/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-community-dialects
    implementation 'org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-community-dialects:6.2.0.Final'

}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And my application.properties

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:sqlite:dbfile.db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.sqlite.JDBC
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.datasource.username = admin
spring.datasource.password = admin
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

But when i launch it i have a :

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class :
> org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-community-dialects

Any idea ?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Downgrade `hibernate-community-dialects` to version **6.1.7.Final**. As with version **6.2.0.Final** its using some class like `AlterTableUniqueDelegate` from `hibernate-core` package but its not exists yet in the hibernate-core version 6.2.0.Final.

Updated **build.gradle** file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.server'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.11.2'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.1.7.Final'
    // https://mavenlibs.com/maven/dependency/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-community-dialects
    implementation 'org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-community-dialects:6.1.7.Final'

}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```